# =IF(Search"",X1)AND(B2<>"")AND(C2<>"")True,False Not working

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I am trying to get a formula to work to search one column for a specific text, then depending if that text contains "Completed", AND 3 other columns are NOT blank, then to Add the number in 3 other columns.

Here is what I have so far that does not work:

```
=if(search("Completed",F1737)AND(AI1737<>"")AND(AF1737<>"")AND(V1737<0))J1737+V1737-W1737-AB1737-AG1737-AJ1737-AL1737,""
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to follow the strict format of the google sheets formulas.

For example, the format of an IF is: `IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

So, for example, you might write an IF that looks like this: `=IF(A1>5, 100, 300)`.  Note that the `value_if_true` (100 in this example) and `value_if_false` (300 in this example) are both inside the parentheses.

In your case, it appears that:

- Your `logical_expression` is `search("Completed",F1737)AND(AI1737<>"")AND(AF1737<>"")AND(V1737<0)`
- Your `value_if_true` is `J1737+V1737-W1737-AB1737-AG1737-AJ1737-AL1737`
- Your `value_if_false` is `""`

In addition, the format for `AND` is `AND(logical_expression1, logical_expression2, ...)`.  Note that `AND` is a function that is written before the logical expressions, not between them, and that the logical expressions are separated by commas, and enclosed in parentheses.

Also, `SEARCH` is a function that returns a position, not a true/false result.  So, you need to check whether the position it returns meets your criteria.

So, a rewritten version of your formula would look something like this:

`=IF(AND(SEARCH("Completed",F1737)=0, AI1737<>"", AF1737<>"", V1737<0), J1737+V1737-W1737, "")`

But you will need to edit this to use the actual criteria you want to apply to search, and to include the rest of the value_if_true part of the IF which I omitted for clarity.

Comment: Amazing that did work! 

Thank you very much.

Would it be possible to also use this with an IFS in the case that the search came up as false?